# Error module.js:540 when trying to run meteor create simple-todos

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, meteor, windows-10

I have installed chocolate via CMD and meteor and the installation went fine. After restarting the computer I tried to launch the meteor create simple-todo command from VSC and I get the following error:

```
module.js:540
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\ameli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\meteor\app\meteor\meteor.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

I have checked this link and there is no meteor folder in the node_module folder.

I also tried the following: clone the git project in the npm node_module and to install it with https://install.meteor.com/windows but it didnt work either

Any suggestion?

Comment: can you please add the exact commands you entered to your cmd after reboot until the error occurred? By the way- node modules are your external package dependencies. It seems you are new to the topic. Maybe this reading can help you: https://guide.meteor.com/atmosphere-vs-npm.html

Comment: So I followed those instructions there, i didn't know there were a npm way to install it. I usually always installed dependencies this way (nodemon, express...). I will have a look at your link and check for one as well. 
The only command I entered after the installation and reboot on VSC was `meteor create simple-todo` which is the one giving me this error.

Comment: I see. So before starting your app you need to enter `meteor npm install`. You may check out guide.meteor.com, it explains the framework really well.

Comment: `meteor npm install` throws me the same error.

I also tried to do a `npm install meteor` or `npm install -g meteor` just in case which leads to the following:
https://pastebin.com/yxGJDYtt

And the logs can be found there: 
https://pastebin.com/Dn0gFnwf

On the guide they didn't say much for the install and running, same as the get started...

Comment: sounds like a failed install. Please try re-installing meteor being sure to run the install from an administrator prompt and then create your project from a standard user prompt

Comment: Reinstalling chocolatey  + meteor via PowerShell seems it works. Via Powershell the `npm install` works and so does the `meteor create simple-todos` but via VSC I get the following:

bash: meteor: command not found

I tried to copy the simple-todos folder and open it via VSC and it works but not completely. Some files could not be copied. I still tried to enter the command `meteor` as per the (blaze) tutorial but I have the same error.
I have installed some meteor extentions on VSC which are Meteor and MeteorHelper. 
Any idea why those commands still don't work on VSC? Thanks!